# Design package hierarchy in java, visibility constraints

Tags: java, visibility, package, hierarchy, class-visibility

I have a package `ts`, containing interfaces for ticket system. I also have `hts` package, containing concrete implementation of `ts`. I have `TicketSystem.class` in `ts`, and `HTicketSystem.class` in `hts` extended from it the first one. `HTicketSystem.class` is the only public class in `hts` package. All other classes in `hts` have default visibility. `hts` package has lots of files, among them java beans. I'd like to extract these beans to sub-package `hts.beans`. The obvious problem then is visibility, because according to `JLS`:

> 7.1   Package Members
>
> ...
>
> The hierarchical naming structure for
>   packages is intended to be convenient
>   for organizing related packages in a
>   conventional manner, but has no
>   significance in itself other than the
>   prohibition against a package having a
>   subpackage with the same simple name
>   as a top level type (§7.6) declared in
>   that package. **There is no special
>   access relationship** between a package
>   named oliver and another package named
>   oliver.twist, or between packages
>   named evelyn.wood and evelyn.waugh.

1) If I leave `beanA.class` with default visibility, it will not be visible to `hts` classes.
2) If I change `beanA.class` to public visibility, it will be visible from outside.

Any suggestion/best practice is highly appreciated.

Comment: what's the problem of making them public?

Comment: Extra visibility. Then one may write something like: ((HTicket)ticket).changeState(....

Comment: or override HTicket to provide custom implementation

Comment: to protect from overriding you can declare class/method as `final`. Considering `((HTicket)ticket).changeState(....` it looks like 3rd party consumer got `ticket` object somehow?